# Form input not being disabled

Tags: plugin-development, form

In the plugin I'm creating I've got a form that has inputs which are set as disabled if they are overridden in a conifg file.

The problem that is occurring is that disabled class is added to the input but the disabled attribute is not.

This is what I've got:

```
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}    
{% set configSettings = craft.config.get('settings', 'myPlugin') %}
{% for paramKey, paramValue in array %}
       {% set disabled = (configSettings[paramKey] is defined) %}
       {# other variable sets here #}
       {{ forms.textField({
            label: paramLabel,
            name: inputName,
            value : paramValue,
            disabled: disabled,
            required: required
            }) }}

{% endfor %}
```

When I navigate to the page, the input field is greyed out but I can still input data to the input field.

This is the HTML that I see when I inspect the element:

```
<input class="text disabled fullwidth" type="text" name="settings[abcd]" value="abc" autocomplete="off">
```

I tried `disabled: true` and `disabled: 1` in the code above to test and the same html is returned.

Comment: Just had a look in the files that make up the text fields and see this line `{%- if disabled is defined and disabled %} disabled {% endif %}` meaning a boolean value should work. I found it in `/craft/app/templates/_includes/forms/text.html`

Answer (score 1):

I copied your markup, setting and name and label manually and it added the `disabled` property if I used `disabled: true`

```
{{ forms.textField({
label: 'Example Label',
name: 'Example Name',
value : 'Example Value',
disabled: true,
required: true
}) }}
```

[image]

Perhaps you could try manually defining the field (as I did) without reading from the variables and confirm that it works.

If that fails, I suggest you [enable dev mode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) and then use [twig's dump() function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) to check that you don't have any errors and that the field is given correct values.

Is there anything in your log file?